# Tree view to table in Excel

Tags: excel, treeview, tabular

I have Data in Treeview and would link to convert it into tabular format; for example:

Available data

***available format:***
[image]

***Required format:***

[image]

Comment: Is this a one-time process? If so, it might be easier to do it by hand. If not -  are the cells merged? If so, you can probably use VBA to easily iterate through the tree and make your new format.

Comment: Dear Benjamin thanks for your response. unfortunately it is not only this table we have a large number to sheets which are required to be shifted. manual work is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried anything to solve this problem? Usually it is best to make a post like this and share what you've tried so far. The way you have posed the question is, "Here is my problem, please solve it for me" - which is more of what you would hire a consultant for, rather than come to a forum for help for specific questions. Also, please provide sample data, not just a screen shot.

That being said, here is the BEGINNING (not complete!) of some code that will get you started. I don't know all of what your data looks like, and what your specific requirements are for formatting to the output, but at least you will be able to iterate through the various columns.

Again, you will need to modify this code to make it meet your needs. It is only meant to give you a *start* to solving your problem. Good luck!

```
Sub convertTreeView()

    Dim i(1 To 5) As Long       'iterators for each column (A to E)
    Dim j As Long               'iterator for Output Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet         'Tab where TreeView exists
    Dim outWS As Worksheet      'Output data on this tab

    'set ws = application.Workbooks("").Worksheets("")  'Fill this is with your workbook/worksheet name
    'set outWS = application.Workbooks("").Worksheets("")  'Fill this is with your workbook/worksheet name

    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set outWS = Sheet2
    j = 1
    For i(1) = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Debug.Print i(1)
            If ws.Cells(i(1), 1) <> "" Then     'New level 1
                'Add new row to outws
                j = j + 1
                outWS.Range("A" & j).Value = ws.Cells(i(1), 1)

                'Add Level 2
                outWS.Range("B" & j).Value = ws.Cells(i(1), 2)

                'Add multiple Level 3
                'INSERT CODE HERE

            End If 'ws.cells(i(1), 1) <> ""

    Next i(1)

End Sub
```